# Nested FieldSet with Collapsible Check-boxes - Compatible with IE8

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to have nested checkboxes that collapse/expand within a fieldset. I've struggled with options that suit javascript and html within ie8 (limitation of the infrastructure and not something I can change). I've spent 5 hours on this and I can't figure out where I've gone awry. I'm also newer to HTML so go easy on me.

Ideally I would see cardiovascular and have the choice1 and choice 2 collapsed and i could click on them respectively to open up checkboxes.

see example:

[image]

I have tried looking at accordions and tree views.

```
<html>

<head>


<script language="Javascript">
 </script>

<style>
body {background-color: white;}
fieldset {
  font-size:12px;
  padding:10px;
  width:320px;
  line-height:1.8;
  height=150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}



legend {
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #e6f9ff ;
    color:black;
    font-size: 16px
    font-faily: Arial
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
    float: left;
    width:100%;

}

h2   {
    border: 2px solid #e6f9ff;
    color:black;
}




</style>


</head>

<form>


<h2><b>Select comorbidities to automatically update the diagnosis list:</b></h2>



<fieldset>

  <legend>Neurological</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Severe Brain Conditions" name="Neurological" value="Severe Brain Conditions" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Severe Brain Conditions">Severe Brain Conditions</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Dementia" name="Neurological" value="Dementia" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Dementia">Dementia</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>



<fieldset>
  <legend>Cardiovascular</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="End Stage Heart Failure" name="Cardiovascular" value="End Stage Heart Failure" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="End Stage Heart Failure">End Stage Heart Failure</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Complication of Cardiac/Vascular Device/Implant/Graft" name="Cardiovascular" value="Complication of Cardiac/Vascular Device/Implant/Graft" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Complication of Cardiac/Vascular Device/Implant/Graft">Complication of Cardiac/Vascular Device/Implant/Graft</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Hypotension" name="Cardiovascular" value="Hypotension" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Hypotension">Hypotension</label>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Pulmonary Heart Disease" name="Cardiovascular" value="Pulmonary Heart Disease" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Pulmonary Heart Disease">Pulmonary Heart Disease</label>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Cardiac Arrythmia" name="Cardiovascular" value="Cardiac Arrythmia" onClick='togglebtn();'></input>
    <label for="Cardiac Arrythmia">Cardiac Arrythmia</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>


<div align="right">
<input type="button" name ='Submit' id ='Submit' disabled = "true" style="color:black" value='Submit' onClick='WriteDx();'></input>
</div>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Start by running that html through an html validator. An `<input>` is a ***void element*** and doesn't have a closing tag. It is self closing. Older IE is not very forgiving with invalid markup

Comment: Will try this and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @charlietfl I have removed the </input>. Do you have an idea on how I solve for the collapsible field-set?

Comment: Will need to do it with javascript. Wrap all the inputs into a container element that you can hide and show when the legend is clicked

Comment: turns out the problem I was having was compatibility with ie. While I have ie11 in this environment, the system had it defaulting to ie8. I am now able to solve this problem. I added a meta tag for the ie version.

Answer (score 0):

I added a meta tag for one problem.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" charset="utf-8">
```

Then solved by doing a collapsible button.

```
 <button class="collapsible"
```